# How to determine camera location from view matrix?

Tags: matrix, graphics, 3d, vertices

for a personal project, I've created a simple 3D engine in python using as little libraries as possible. I did what I wanted - I am able to render simple polygons, and have a movable camera. However, there is a problem:

I implemented a simple flat shader, but in order for it to work, I need to know the camera location (the camera is my light source). However, the problem is that I have no way of knowing the camera's location in the world space. At any point, I am able to display my view matrix, but I am unsure about how to extract the camera's location from it, especially after I rotate the camera. Here is a screenshot of my engine with the view matrix. The camera has not been rotated yet and it is very simple to extract its location (0, 1, 4).
[image]

However, upon moving the camera to a point between the X and Z axes and pointing it upwards (and staying at the same height), the view matrix changes to this:

[image]

It is obvious now that the last column cannot be taken directly to determine the camera location (it should be something like (4,1,4) on the last picture).

I have tried a lot of math, but I can't figure out the way to determine the camera x,y,z location from the view matrix. I will appreciate any and all help in solving this, as it seems to be a simple problem, yet whose solution eludes me. Thank you.

EDIT:
I was advised to transform a vertex (0,0,0,1) by my view matrix. This, however, does not work. See the example (the vertex obviously is not located at the printed coordinates):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just take the transform of the vector `(0,0,0,1)` with the modelview matrix: Which is simply the rightmost column of the modelview matrix.

*EDIT*: @ampersander: I wonder why you're trying to work with the camera location in the first place, if you assume the source of illumination to be located at the camera's position. In that case, just be aware, that in OpenGL there is no such thing as a camera, and in fact, what the "view" transform does, is move everything in the world around so that where you assume your camera to be ends up at the coordinate origin (0,0,0).

Or in other words: After the modelview transform, the transformed vertex position is in fact the vector from the camera to the vertex, in view space. Which means that for your assumed illumination calculation the direction toward the light source, is the negative vertex position. Take that, normalize it to unit length and stick it into the illumination term.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not work. See my edit